# Is there an equivalent of less for SQL*Plus?

Tags: sql, unix, pipe, sqlplus

Sometimes a query on [SQL*Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL*Plus) might yield too many rows t fit on the screen.

Is there some equivalent of "piping to less/more" mechanism that I can do to navigate the results?

```
select * from emp | less
```

Comment: Cool - in the past, I'd just SPOOL the output to a file & review the file.  Seeing rows at a command prompt leads me to changing the line size so I can read the output...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SET PAUSE ON` see http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3369501/SQLPlus-Tips-for-Oracle-Beginners.htm

Answer (score 1):

Does SQL*Plus not allow you to run its commands from the shell? It's been a while since I used it but I though it did.

I know with DB2 you can just do:

```
db2 'select * from sysibm.sysdummy1' | less
```

at the command line and let the shell handle the paging.

If not, I'd just create an `sql++` script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo connect pax/diablo >/tmp/sql++.$$
echo "$@" >>/tmp/sql++.$$
sqlplus @/tmp/sql++.$$
rm -rf /tmp/sql++.$$
```

and use it:

```
sql++ 'select * from dual' | less
```

That way you get the full power of `less` paging, being able to scroll up and down, search and so on.