# Does SQL*Plus natively allow queries to run from the shell itself?

Tags: sql, unix, pipe, sqlplus

For example, is there equivalent of these in SQL*Plus

```
sqlplus 'SELECT * FROM emp' | less 
sqlplus 'SELECT * FROM emp' | grep Primx
```

One way has been suggested by [paxdiablo here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446349/is-there-an-equivalent-of-less-for-sqlplus/3446365#3446365). Is that the only way?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the online docs to support it, which is why I posted that bizarre (though workable) solution. I had a vague recollection from using SQL*Plus many, _many_ moons ago that you could, provided you used operating system security rather than Oracle security but maybe that's changed, or I'm misremembering - I hear that happens when the years advance :-). I'm a DB2 man nowadays so I'm not overly concerned. And I think you have your `grep` and `less` may be in the wrong order, BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with here documents:

```
sqlplus  -S user/password << EOF | grep Primx
select * from emp;
EOF
```

-S is for silent mode, followed by username and password combination.

Comment: I'm happy it helped :)
here documents give you the ability to "feed" input into an interactive program. you can read more about it here:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html